# Summer '19 Sandbox error: String index out of range: 0: Source

Tags: aura, summer19

This is a self-answered question in case anyone else is looking.
The Summer '19 sandboxes dropped over the weekend and I started getting the above error this morning. It was only on 1 Aura component but it was a base component so affected lots else. The component refused to save and ceased displaying in the community.

Answer (score 8):

Turns out the component had a css file that only contained '/**/'. I deleted the file and all is working again.

Answer (score 0):

Removing empty CSS comments (/**/) from the CSS file will solve the issue. 
Also, I've noticed that components are not getting loaded in community builder for the same reason. Removing empty CSS comments from CSS files will fix all these issues.

Comment: This answer is basically just a repeat of what's already posted.

Comment: The previous answer is talking about deleting the CSS file which is not the case (which is not required). I've tried to add a comment on that. since I'm new I don't have access to add a comment on that. Hence posted a new answer.